# How would you build this exact stone wall?

Tags: uv

[image]
What is your suggested way to build a wall with a texture like this.

Or how would you UV-unwrap the modelled wall, to enable the texture of the stripes to work.

Im currently trying around but dont want to manually drag the uv map into a rectangle
[image]

Comment: Could you upload your blend file to: http://blend-exchange.giantcowfilms.com/? Also don't forget to pack a texture in blend file. It would be much easier to answer.

Comment: have you tried project form view?

Comment: Try the UV squares addon